# obtaining kernel build tree

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

Could anyone explain me what the kernel build tree is?

What files does it include?

How can I obtain it from a cross-compiled kernel source (e.g. 3.4.0)?

Comment: Which distro are you dealing with or do you mean just in general?

Comment: @slm: I am using an old Debian (lenny)

Answer (score 1):

well the kernel build tree, is the kernel source itself

to get it an "install" it you should:

1. download kernel you want at www.kernel.org (in your case 3.4.0).
2. extract to /usr/src
3. ln -s linux-xxxxx linux

I think you can download it as well via apt like `sudo apt-get install linux-source` (if you need the 3.4.0 make sure that your debian has it as package)

With the information that you want to cross-compile your kernel to load it in an external device, I will assume that you want to do it for an arm-based device http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/docs/kerncomp.php if it's not, you can easily adapt it to another plataform

Comment: 1) what is linux-xxxx linux? what are you linking to what? 2) it is a cross-compiled kernel, I will load it to a microsd card, if I softlink it to the linux directory, won't there be a broken link since I will insert the microSD into another device, I really could not understand how do you link files and where? If you are linking the whole kernel source which is 454 MB. But the kernel header that can be downloaded by `apt-get` is significantly smaller.

Comment: if you want to compile it and load it in a microsd card you should write it in your question. The xxxx is the version from the kernel that you downloaded. I will update my answer based on your new informaiton